# jquery check all with each checkbox 'change' function

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery on my page which selects all checkboxes with a class of CheckInvoice

```
$("#checkAllInvoices").click(function(){
    $('.checkInvoice').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

i then have this which sees the change on the checkbox

```
$('#check').on('change', function() {

}

$('#check1').on('change', function() {

}

$('#check2').on('change', function() {

}
```

the 'on change' jquery works fine when i select each checkbox however when i use the check all, its not recognising it as a 'change'

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with id `check`? The jQuery selector only returns the first match in the case of multiple matching IDs. Please make sure IDs are unique. You may need to change the `on('#check')` to `on('.checkInvoice')`. Additionally, setting `checked` with `prop` may not fire the event. If that's the case, trigger the event with `$(...).trigger('change');`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You question is not clear.

Comment: It's not clear enough. Please make a fiddle

Comment: sorry, i missed some code off. check my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on.

Firstly, can't see your HTML, but it seems like maybe you're using `check` as an `id` for every check box.  This won't work, an `id` must be unique.  I've replaced this with just using your check box class.

Secondly, you're trying to set the state of each checkbox based on the `checkAllInvoices` checkbox - but you're not iterating through each of them - you're just changing the state of the `checkAllInvoices` element.  I've also removed the `checkInvoice` class from the `checkAllInvoices` element so you don't need to do the `not(this)` test

Thirdly (and the real answer), you need to trigger the change function to occur - not just change the state of the property

```js
"use strict";

function init() {
    $("#checkAllInvoices").click(function(){
        var checked = this.checked;
        $('.checkInvoice').each(
            function() {
                if (this.checked != checked) $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        );
    });

    $('.checkInvoice').on('change', function() {
        console.log(this.value)
    });
}

$( document ).ready(init)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form name="test">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkInvoice" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkInvoice" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkInvoice" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" class="checkInvoice" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" class="checkInvoice" value="5">5<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllInvoices">check all<br />
<br />
</form>
</body>
```